# C# How to wait X seconds for a task to complete

Tags: c#, task, delay

I want to wait for a task to complete for a specified amount of time without blocking the thread and based on whether the task is complete or not perform some work.
e.g. waiting for an HTTP request for a specific amount of time.

Comment: Do you want to keep checking 'MyCondition' until its true but 'timeout' after x seconds? So if MyCondition was true, you would return immediately but if it never evaluated true, then you would wait x seconds for it potentially change and if not return? or do you want to always waiting x seconds?

Comment: @Dave first one

Comment: You're getting wacky answers because people don't understand what you're trying to do. What is the difference between “return something after `sec`” and “during of `sec`”? What is `MyCondition`? Instead of showing us what you're trying to do, [describe your goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: @DourHighArch i am sorry.it is obviously my flaw ,because i talking English so bad.
best example of what i want to do is a program that check for internet connection at the begining. this program for 2 seconds checking internet connection and if there is a connection program going to next step immediately and if there is no connection after 2 seconds 
user can click on a button to retry for connecting to the internet.
that's what i want to build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can use a CancellationTokenSource which will set the tokens IsCancellationRequested property to true if the period elapsed. Thus your code would be.

```
public bool TrySomething(int sec)
{
    var ct = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec)).Token;
    var valueToReturne=false;
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (!MyCondition)
                    continue;
        else
                    valueToReturne = true;
    }
    return valueToReturne;
}
```

However, similar to the other solutions this is a busy loop meaning block your main thread.

If you want you stop to program from not responding you would need to make your method async, e.g. by wrapping TrySomething in Task.Run, e.g.

```
var ct = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec)).Token;
await Task.Run(() => TrySomething(ct), ct);

public bool TrySomething(CancellationToken ct)
{
    var valueToReturne=false;
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (!MyCondition)
                    continue;
        else
                    valueToReturne = true;
    }
    return valueToReturne;
}
```

However, this should only be done for CPU-bound work. But you are stating you want to check your internet connection, which is IO-bound work. You could still use Task.Run, but this is heavily frowned upon in this case. The optimal solution would be to use proper async methods for your internet connection check, e.g. if you are using Ping.Send to check for an internet connection, you should use Ping.SendAsync and so on.

In this case your code would be:

```
var ct = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec)).Token;
await TrySomething(ct);

public async Task<bool> TrySomethingAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    var valueToReturne=false;
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (!await MyConditionAsync(ct))
                    continue;
        else
                    valueToReturne = true;
    }
    return valueToReturne;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Calculate your ending time, then wait until that time passes.

```
public void TrySomething(int sec)
{
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(sec);
    while (DateTime.Now < endTime)
    {
         // do useful stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: for `sec` second application does not responding.i want application responding during of the loop.

Comment: Don't use `DateTime` - use `Stopwatch` for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

`Stopwatch` is the way to go here:

```
public void TrySomething(int sec)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < (double)sec)
    {
         // do useful stuff
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
public void TrySomething(int sec)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (true)
    {
        var result = ...
        // do useful stuff
        if (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds >= (double)sec)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```